# Force Work - Line Integral

Tags: calculus, integration, vector-analysis

I have a question that I would like to know the solution

Find the work of strength

$$\vec{F}(x,y) = y\vec{i} + y^2\vec{j}$$

When moving a unit of mass from the point $(0,0)$ to the point $(3,1)$ along the rectilinear segment between these points.

Why is it not possible to apply the formula $\int \vec{F}d\vec{r}$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean it is not possible?

Comment: And what do you mean by rectilinear segment?

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can :

The line between the points $ (0,0) $ and $ (3,1) $ can be parametrised as
$$x=0+(3-0)t=3t$$
$$y=0+(1-0)t=t$$

then
$$\vec{F}•\vec{dl}=(y,y^2)•(dx,dy)$$
$$=ydx+y^2dy$$
$$t(3dt)+(t^2)(dt)=(3t+t^2)dt$$

thus the work will be

$$W=\int_0^1(3t+t^2)dt=\Bigl[3\frac{t^2}{2}+\frac{t^3}{3}\Bigr]_0^1$$
$$=\frac{11}{6}$$